# Google Places API Autocomplete search ACCESS DENIED ERROR: FLUTTER (Issue Not Resolved)

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to use the Autocomplete search (places suggestions) feature of **Google Maps Platform** using the **Places API**.
***The API KEY I am using is restricted to a single user (i.e., me) on the Maps Platform.***
**Approach-1:**

```
 Future<void> onChanged(String value) async {
    print('onChanged() called!');
    if (_sessionToken == null) {
      setState(() {
        _sessionToken = uuid.v4();
      });
    }
    if (isFocused) await getSuggestion(value);
  }

  Future<void> getSuggestion(String input) async {
    print('getSuggestion() called $input');
    String type = '(regions)';
    String components = 'country';
    //print('Inside getSuggestion lat=${provider.latitude}');
    String request =
        '$baseURL?input=$input&key=$API_KEY&sessiontoken=$_sessionToken&location=${appState.startLatLng.latitude},${appState.startLatLng.longitude}&radius=50000&components=country:in';
    print('suggestion request url: $request');
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(request));
    print('Response is ${response.body}');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        predictions = jsonDecode(response.body)['predictions'];
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load predictions');
    }
  }
```

**Problem-**
But, when I use it on my Android Phone I get the following error response:

```
{
"error_message": "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address <MY IP HERE>, with empty referer",
"predictions": [],
"status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

**Approach-2** using https://pub.dev/packages/google_place
**Place Autocomplete**

```
var googlePlace = GooglePlace("Your-Key");
var result = await googlePlace.autocomplete.get("1600 Amphitheatre");
```

**Problem-**  Empty Search suggestion list and request denied status

> Search suggestion result: [] REQUEST_DENIED

**Please help me understand what the problem is and how to rectify.**
One of the associated problem is-
[Not able to fetch polyline polypoints because of restricted Google Maps API Key: Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73714935/not-able-to-fetch-polyline-polypoints-because-of-restricted-google-maps-api-key)

Comment: If you use an unrestricted API key, does it work? Are you not getting any error?

Comment: I am using a restricted api key which only permits access through android sdk. Without restriction it works fine.